# AJAX and Java - Update Stocks

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring

I am building a stock-based trading application and I am using Yahoo finance to get the prices for stocks.

I would like the prices to be updated every 5 seconds without having to refresh the page. I need to implement this using AJAX

Java controller:

```
@GetMapping("/banking/stocks")
public String stocks(Model model) {

model.addAttribute("stock", new StockDto());
try {
    List<Stock> stocks = stockService.getDefaultStocks(getCurrentUser());
    model.addAttribute("stocks", stocks);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return "stocks.html";
}
```

HTML:

```
<tbody>
<tr th:each="stock : ${stocks}">
    <td th:text="'$'+${stock.getSymbol()}"></td>                                                    
    <td th:text="${stock.getName()}"></td>
    <td th:text="${stock.getQuote().getPrice()}"></td>
    <td
        th:class="${stock.getQuote().getChangeInPercent() > 0 ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'}"
        th:text="${stock.getQuote().getChangeInPercent() + '%'} "></td>
    <td th:if="${stock.getDividend().getAnnualYield() != null}"
        th:text="${stock.getDividend().getAnnualYield() + '%'}">0.00%</td>
    <td th:if="${stock.getDividend().getAnnualYield() == null}">0.00%</td>
</tr>
```

How can I implement AJAX so that getPrice() is called every 5 seconds and updated on the page? This has been a major issue for me and I must fix it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

thmyleaf is a template engine , so when the page has showed the value will be set
if you want a dynamic price you should use Javascript to replace html content instead of thmyleaf

Here is a simple Demo

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/chawol/pen/oNzaXdg)
```